# Strange CSS behaviour with font shorthand

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="timer">00:01:05</div>
```

The following css generates a 154x30px box:

```
div.timer
{

    font: 700 24px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

and this one generates a 154x19px box (on the sam div element).

```
div.timer
{
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

How can this be possible? I checked the shorthand property and i can't find what I'm doing wrong. I ordered the attributes in the good order, of that I'm preety sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use a shorthand property, any value you don't specify is reset to the default.

So the first example changes the font-style, font-variant and line-height. The line-height in particular is likely to alter the box size.

Comment: @Quentin: did you mean the browser's default?! I usually start a CSS file by resetting all elements because I want to minimize the browser's influence. Do I get that influence back in through the back door if I use shorthand properties?